# Does a finite set of sets with the following property always have a biggest and smallest element?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\boldsymbol{\mathscr{S}}$ be a finite set having as elements other sets $X_{1},...,Xn$.

(1) For every T,Z, if they both belong to $\boldsymbol{\mathscr{S}}$, then $T\subseteq Z $or $Z\subseteq T
$

Then, given (1) there exist a “biggest” and “smallest” element of $\boldsymbol{\mathscr{S}}$, one that includes any other element but that is not properly included in any other.

Intuitively, this is valid. Although I am not sure how to prove it:

We could assume for contradiction that there does not exists a $Y\in\boldsymbol{\mathscr{S}}$ such that for every $X\in\boldsymbol{\mathscr{S}}$, $X\subseteq Y$. This means that taking any X, we would always have an X' that properly includes X, and the same for an X'' that properly includes X', going ad infinitum. But this contradicts the assumption that $\boldsymbol{\mathscr{S}}$ is a finite set, therefore there must exists a $Y\in\boldsymbol{\mathscr{S}}$ such that for every $X\in\boldsymbol{\mathscr{S}}$, $X\subseteq Y$.

Is this a correct way of answering the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I did not read your question properly. Yes, what you wrote is also correct!

Here  is another idea:

Consider the following process:
Take $X=X_1$. If $X_1\subsetneq X_2$, then X=X_2. Otherwise $X=X_1$.
Repeat this process $n$ times. Then $X$ is the “biggest” element in $\mathcal{S}$. Indeed, suppose for the sake of contradiction, that there exists some $X_i\in \mathcal{S}$ such that $X\subsetneq X_i$. Then at step $i$ of the process, $X$ would have become $X_i$. So you get a contradiction.

You can do the same for the "smalest" element.